# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' even when dtype of object is a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list named 'state_lists' and I have a dataframe with column named 'ADDRESS'. I want to create a new column in my dataframe by

1. iterating through the ADDRESS column
2. if a state from the 'state_lists' is found in the ADDRESS column, the state is extrated into another column named STATE

I used this code below, before and and it worked but now it shows the error above

```
df["STATE"] = df["ADDRESS"].map(lambda x: state if ( state:=x.split()[-1]) in state_lists else np.nan)
```

What would be the problem now? I have checked the data type for the Address column and it is an object. This code has worked before dont know what is happening now?

I make sure I replaced all the null values with an object still the same error message pops up

Comment: What about `x.str.split()`? Hard to say without any data provided

Comment: I actually got this error after trying that out  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have `int` in your field `ADDRESS`. You can add a conditional statement to check if the value in `ADDRESS` is an instance of `string` before applying `split()` function. You can implement it as:

```
import numpy as np

def extract_state(address):
    if isinstance(address, str):
        state = address.split()[-1]
        return state if state in state_lists else np.nan
    else:
        return np.nan

df["STATE"] = df["ADDRESS"].map(extract_state)
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to ask, what if the word and state to be extracted is not the last word in the address?

Comment: @Engr.Chinwe in that case, you will need to apply `split` to each address, loop through the resulting spilts (which will be individual words), and then in the loop check the word that matches the `state_lists` and return it as state, else return `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use :

```
import re

pat = fr'\b({"|".join(map(re.escape, state_lists))})\b'

df["STATE"] = df["ADDRESS"].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
```